# JPA: how to change reference id without creating of new object

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, many-to-one

for example, I have entity Employee that refers to Department

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, 
           cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})    
private Department department;
```

I want to save new Employee, but I already know Department id (it is 9L). Right now I save it like

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
final Employee emp = new Employee();            
emp.setFirstName("A");
emp.setLastName("L");
emp.setDepartment(em.getReference(Department.class, 9L));
em.persist(emp);    
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

So, each time I need to find Department in DB, or, at least, get object from proxy, and then call `setDepartment`.

Is it possible to set department_id of Employee instance without creating new Department object?

Thanks.

Comment: I have not tried that with EclipseLink but it should be enough to create a new Department instance with the needed id for setting the dependency.

Comment: First, I want to avoid of new class Instances. Second, it will try to save new Department object, as it is cascade persist. So in this case, it will create new Department object with auto-incremented id and empty name.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.  Your cascading rules require a reference to an existing Department or a new one will be created.

http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/09/25/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/

CascadeType.PERSIST : means that save() or persist() operations cascade to related entities.

CascadeType.MERGE : means that related entities are merged into managed state when the owning entity is merged.

If you want to avoid the look up, you'll need to change your cascade rules.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it comes at a cost.  You would need to make the Employee->Department reference read-only (insertable=false, updatable=false) to allow you to add a basic mapping to the Employee to use to set the department_ID directly.  You then will be responsible for setting the department ID manually in each case, and note that the Employee.department reference may become out of synch if you do not maintain it.  That means if you do not set the relationship, it may be null even though the basic mapping for the field has a value until you force a refresh.

Ie:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
final Employee emp = new Employee();            
emp.setFirstName("A");
emp.setLastName("L");
emp.setDepartment_id(9L);
em.persist(emp);    
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

and if needed:

```
em.refresh(emp);
```

Comment: Thanks. No, that is too complicated. I understand that I can process field manually. I want to find a way to get department_id, though this field was created automatically by manager and has no explicit getters or setters.

Comment: I don't quite get the context of your comment and what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to find a way to get department_id field of table and set it's value. This field was created automatically, by EclipseLink. In fact, I do not even know exactly, that this field has name "department_id", I found that information in database. I just know, that this field is set when I set id of Department object and set department to Employee. There are two ways 1) to create object every time 2) use your approach. I want a convenient way to work with models, but there are some performance problems. I need to reduce number of db requests to 3 instead of 6.

Comment: A 3rd option is to map objects as flat without any relationships.  This will give you better control over the performance if you know what you are doing, but costs you convenience as you would need to look up departments manually when needed.  What I suggested is a bridge between the two.